# MySql not getting the desired output

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

`product`

`attributes` - in which I have colour and size

`attribute value` - in which I have red white black small medium large with its matching attributeID

If we select one product such as car and one attribute such as colour. My output should be

```
car_red ,car_white ,car_black
```

and now if we select one product and 2 attributes such as colour and size my output should be

```
car_red_small, car_red_med, car_red_large, car_white_s,car_white_m
```

for all the colours now I am getting the first output with one attributes but in second one I am getting output as

```
car_red,car_white,car_black,car_small,car_medium,car_large
```

this is my code which I have tried can you please help me with this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_variation_concat`(
    IN _Product_type varchar(255),
    IN _Attribute varchar(255)
    )

    SELECT CONCAT(w.Product_type,'_',m.Attribute_value) AS 'Variation'
    FROM Product w, Attribute_value m 
    where Product_type = _Product_type 
    and  m.AttributeID = find_in_set(m.AttributeID,_Attribute);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too disorganized to get much help here. There is very little punctuation and it's difficult to understand. It would also help if the queries were highlighted and you select the code format button, so that the code is separate from the question.

For the question itself, I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have 3 tables names as Products in which product_type is written which Is car,bike,etc. second table names as attributes in which I have colour and size.in third table I have attributes value such as red, blue,small, large etc and infront of it in other column I have matching attributeID for join now I want output as car_red_small,car_red_large I tried but not getting this desired output using my code can you help me with this

Comment: It's `YEAR(CURDATE())`, the **ANSI-92** explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as A_Very_Long_Time`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's better to query the tables separately and do the concatenation in the application level. But if you need to do it in MySQL, I guess you will need to dynamically generate the query based on the number of attributes that you want to select.

For example, given this data:

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE products (
  id varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE attributes (
  id varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE attribute_values (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  attribute_id varchar(255),
  name varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id) references attributes(id)
);


-- insert
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('car');
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('bike');
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES ('color');
INSERT INTO attributes VALUES ('size');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (1, 'color', 'red');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (2, 'color', 'green');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (3, 'color', 'blue');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (4, 'size', 'small');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (5, 'size', 'medium');
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (6, 'size', 'large');
```

if you want to select 2 attributes for `car`, the query will be:

```
SELECT concat(p.id, '_', a1.av, '_', a2.av) as name FROM 
(SELECT id FROM products) p join
(SELECT av.name as av FROM attributes a join attribute_values av on a.id = av.attribute_id where a.id = 'color') a1 join
(SELECT av.name as av FROM attributes a join attribute_values av on a.id = av.attribute_id where a.id = 'size') a2
where p.id = 'car';
```

Output:

```
name
car_red_small
car_red_medium
car_red_large
car_green_small
car_green_medium
car_green_large
car_blue_small
car_blue_medium
car_blue_large
```

Try the query online https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3ytkftx6r

Comment: thank you sir for this but we have to choose which attributes we want to add for our products and how many attributes we want to can you help me with that?

Comment: for example my car wants one attribute-colour so my variation would be like car_red,car_white,car_black now if my product car wants two attributes-colour, size so my output should be like one which is shown above now we can choose as many attributes as we want our output should depend on it

Comment: I am getting an error as av. Name doesn't exist